# dropdown menu not showing in Spring / Java

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, render, dropdown

Anyone have an idea why my drop down options are not rendering in my form? I have this html form rendering but the options dont appear. I also have the form input fields in a model, listed as private String businessClass; and then a getter and setter for it as well. Am I missing something?

```html
<div class="row">
            <label for="businessClass" >Business Class: </label>
            <select class="select-2 form-control" field="*{businessClass}" id="businessClass" >
                    <option value="Animal Services">Animal Services</option>
                    <option value="Arts Entertainment">Arts &amp; Entertainment</option>
                    <option value="Auto Services">Auto Services</option>
                    <option value="bonds">Bonds</option>
                    
             </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem. If you are using thymeleaf you must bind properties with

```
th:field="*{...}"
```

and not only

```
field="*{}".
```

Maybe there are more issues, but that's the problem located in the given snippet.